Columns of Data missing on Google Sheet file after upload
I have this program that is supposed to take some csv files using pandas and convert them to google sheet files and upload them to my Google Drive folder. However, when uploaded, only the last 8 columns appear starting from the second row.
Here is my program:
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
import os

# Authenticate using credentials
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = r'C:\Users\SLIDES-PR_8\Documents\slides_network\client_keys_api_drive.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create Google Drive and Sheets services
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# Function to upload CSV file as Google Sheets
def upload_csv_as_sheet(csv_file_path, folder_id):
    try:
        # Extract file name without extension
        file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file_path))[0]

        # Define data types for columns
        dtype_dict = {
            'TIMESTAMP': 'str',  # Assuming TIMESTAMP is in string format
            'RECORD': 'int',  # Assuming RECORD is in integer format
            'BattV_Min': 'float',
            'PanelTemp_C': 'float',
            'Rain_mm_Tot': 'float',
            'rain_cum': 'float',
            'air_temp': 'float',
            'atmos_pressure': 'float',
            'piezTemp': 'float',
            'Lvl': 'float',
            'suction1_20cm': 'float',
            'suction2_40cm': 'float',
            'suction3_60cm': 'float',
            'wc1_20cm': 'float',
            'wc2_40cm': 'float',
            'wc3_60cm': 'float',
            'wc4_80cm': 'float'
        }

        # Read CSV file into pandas DataFrame with specified data types and parse dates
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, dtype=dtype_dict)

        # Include headers as the first row in the values list
        headers = df.columns.tolist()
        values = [headers] + df.values.tolist()

        # Create new Google Sheets spreadsheet
        body = {
            'properties': {
                'title': file_name
            }
        }
        spreadsheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets().create(body=body,
                                                           fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
        spreadsheet_id = spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')

        # Write data from DataFrame to the newly created Google Sheets
        range_name = 'Sheet1'  # Adjust this as needed
        value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'

        body = {
            'values': values
        }
        result = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
            valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()

        # Move the newly created Google Sheets to the specified folder in Google Drive
        drive_service.files().update(
            fileId=spreadsheet_id,
            addParents=folder_id,
            removeParents='root',
            fields='id, parents'
        ).execute()

        print(f'File uploaded as Google Sheets to Google Drive: {spreadsheet_id}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error uploading file {csv_file_path}: {e}')
        if hasattr(e, 'resp') and e.resp.status == 404:
            print("The specified folder ID does not exist or is not accessible.")
        elif hasattr(e, 'resp') and e.resp.status == 403:
            print("The service account does not have permission to access the specified folder.")
        else:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

# Path to the folder containing CSV files
folder_path = r'C:\Campbellsci\LoggerNet'

# Specify the Google Drive folder ID where you want to upload files
folder_id = '18lRmVICZy__WFpf_VK1N5dUHRnafJLxn'

# List all CSV files in the folder
dat_files = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.dat')]

# Iterate through each CSV file and upload as Google Sheets
for dat_file in dat_files:
    upload_csv_as_sheet(dat_file, folder_id)


Here is the csv data: :
"TOA5","Adjuntas","CR1000X","31923","CR1000X.Std.05.01","CPU:adjuntas.CR1X","39973","t24hr"
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","BattV_Min","PanelTemp_C","Rain_mm_Tot","rain_cum","air_temp","atmos_pressure","piezTemp","Lvl","suction1_20cm","suction2_40cm","suction3_60cm","wc1_20cm","wc2_40cm","wc3_60cm","wc4_80cm"
"TS","RN","Volts","","mm","cm","degC","kPa","degC","mh20","kPa","kPa","kPa","vol water/total vol","vol water/total vol","vol water/total vol","vol water/total vol"
"","","Min","Smp","Tot","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp"
"2022-03-31 00:00:00",0,12.41,16.2,0.508,0.051,15.47156,101.583,18.1,-0.004326403,-0.3,-0.6,-6,0.5113982,0.4228129,0.4587201,0.409934
"2022-04-01 00:00:00",1,12.37,16.84,0.254,0.076,15.96344,101.6667,18.11,0.003971517,-0.2,-0.7,-7.8,0.5113389,0.420531,0.4575319,0.4095327
"2022-04-02 00:00:00",2,12.39,16.74,0,0.076,15.89624,101.7488,18.11,0.01235151,-0.2,-0.8,-9.9,0.5108751,0.4183866,0.4565127,0.4091883

And here is the result I am getting:
[['Lvl', 'suction1_20cm', 'suction2_40cm', 'suction3_60cm', 'wc1_20cm', 'wc2_40cm', 'wc3_60cm', 'wc4_80cm'], ['mh20', 'kPa', 'kPa', 'kPa', 'vol water/total vol', 'vol water/total vol', 'vol water/total vol', 'vol water/total vol'], ['Smp', 'Smp', 'Smp', 'Smp', 'Smp', 'Smp', 'Smp', 'Smp'], ['-0.004326403', '-0.3', '-0.6', '-6', '0.5113982', '0.4228129', '0.4587201', '0.409934'], ['0.003971517', '-0.2', '-0.7', '-7.8', '0.5113389', '0.420531', '0.4575319', '0.4095327'], ['0.01235151', '-0.2', '-0.8', 
'-9.9', '0.5108751', '0.4183866', '0.4565127', '0.4091883'], ['-0.009841561', '-0.2', '-1', '-11', '0.5102451', '0.4161375', '0.4557474', '0.4088359'], ['-0.01827794', 
'-0.1', '-1.6', '-12', '0.5096161', '0.4140894', '0.4549248', '0.4083987'], ['-0.01046139', '-0.1', '-2.7', '-12.8', '0.5087664', '0.4123285', '0.4543619', '0.4078622'], ['-0.00499469', '-0.1', '-4.6', '-13.5', '0.5080001', '0.4104707', '0.453402', '0.4073801'], ['-0.004209459', '-0.2', '-6.6', '-14.2', '0.5071166', '0.4090789', '0.4525868', '0.4069061']

As you may be able to see, the 'lvl' column is the 8th last column on the csv file but the first of the sheet file. I think that the df.value.to_list() line may have something to do with it.

Using the python csv library instead seems to have resolved the issue and I am now getting all the data on my Sheets file.
 # Extract file name without extension
        file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file_path))[0]

        # Open CSV file and read headers and data
        with open(csv_file_path, mode='r', newline='') as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            headers = next(reader)  # First row is headers
            data = list(reader)  # Remaining rows are data

        # Create values list for Google Sheets API
        values = [headers] + data


I am still curious as to why pandas maybe had issues reading the data types or if it was something else.
